# Spark UDAF - using generics as input type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I want to write Spark UDAF where type of the column could be any that has a Scala Numeric defined on it. I've searched over Internet but found only examples with concrete types like `DoubleType`, `LongType`. Isn't this possible? But how then use that UDAFs with other numeric values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simplicity let's assume you want to define a custom `sum`. You'll have provide a `TypeTag` for the input type and use Scala reflection to define schemas:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.schemaFor

case class MySum [T : TypeTag](implicit n: Numeric[T]) 
    extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  val dt = schemaFor[T].dataType
  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", dt)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("x", dt)

  def dataType = dt
  def deterministic = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = buffer.update(0,  n.zero)
  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    if (!input.isNullAt(0))
      buffer.update(0, n.plus(buffer.getAs[T](0), input.getAs[T](0)))
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    buffer1.update(0, n.plus(buffer1.getAs[T](0),  buffer2.getAs[T](0)))    
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = buffer.getAs[T](0)
}
```

With a function defined as above we can create instance handling specific types:

```
val sumOfLong = MySum[Long]
spark.range(10).select(sumOfLong($"id")).show
```

```
+---------+
|mysum(id)|
+---------+
|       45|
+---------+
```

**Note**:

To get the same flexibility as the built-in aggregate functions you'd have to define your own `AggregateFunction`, like [`ImperativeAggregate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/101556d0fa704deca0f4a2e5070906d4af2c861b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala#L233) or [`DeclarativeAggregate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/101556d0fa704deca0f4a2e5070906d4af2c861b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala#L336). It is possible, but it is an internal API.

Comment: How can we extend this to support input schema which is dynamic? i.e we are not sure about the input schema. Can we have a generic input schema?

Comment: @VijayMuvva Make schema parameter of the constructor.