# Spark UDAF generics type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-aggregate

I'm trying to create an UDAF on Spark (2.0.1, Scala 2.11) as below. This is to essentially aggregates tuples and output a `Map`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, Column}

class mySumToMap[K, V](keyType: DataType, valueType: DataType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  override def inputSchema = new StructType()
    .add("a_key", keyType)
    .add("a_value", valueType)

  override def bufferSchema = new StructType()
    .add("buffer_map", MapType(keyType, valueType))

  override def dataType = MapType(keyType, valueType)

  override def deterministic = true 

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer(0) = Map[K, V]()
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {

    // input :: 0 = a_key (k), 1 = a_value
    if ( !(input.isNullAt(0)) ) {

      val a_map = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[K, V]]
      val k = input.getAs[K](0)  // get the value of position 0 of the input as string (a_key)

      // I've split these on purpose to show that return values are all of type V
      val new_v1: V = a_map.getOrElse(k, 0.asInstanceOf[V])
      val new_v2: V = input.getAs[V](1)
      val new_v: V = new_v1 + new_v2

      buffer(0) = if (new_v != 0) a_map + (k -> new_v) else a_map - k
    }
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    val map1: Map[K, V] = buffer1(0).asInstanceOf[Map[K, V]]
    val map2: Map[K, V] = buffer2(0).asInstanceOf[Map[K, V]]

    buffer1(0) = map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k, 0.asInstanceOf[V])) }
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row) = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[K, V]]

}
```

But when I compile this, I see the below error:

```
<console>:74: error: type mismatch;
 found   : V
 required: String
             val new_v: V = new_v1 + new_v2
                                     ^
<console>:84: error: type mismatch;
 found   : V
 required: String
           buffer1(0) = map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k, 0.asInstanceOf[V])) }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** For the folks marking this as a duplicate of [Spark UDAF - using generics as input type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248719/spark-udaf-using-generics-as-input-type) - this is not a duplicate of that issue, as that one does not deal with **Map** datatype. The above code is very specific and complete regarding the problem faced using the Map datatype.

Comment: Why do you assume type `V` has a `+` operator (method)? You didn't bound it to be anything specific, so it could be any class, including classes that don't define this operator. Do you wish to bound `V` to be any _numeric_ type?

Comment: @TzachZohar Looks like this error has got something to do with the way I'm doing addition? In your [CombineMaps](https://gist.github.com/tzachz/c976a1080b6379ef861c142c16f1364a) example (which is really great! BTW), I tried to get rid of the `merge` (as I need only addition in my use case). The statement `val result = map1 ++ map2.map{case(k,v) => k -> map1.get(k).map(v + _).getOrElse(v) }` is throwing the exact error as above!

Comment: That's exactly why this `merge` argument is necessary there: for a generic type `V`, how would the UDAF know how to combine two values into one? For numeric values, `+` is a good option, but for non-numeric ones that don't have `+` operator defined - you'd need the caller to supply a matching function. Anyway - you got a good answer here from @user8371915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict types to the ones having `Numeric[_]`

```
class mySumToMap[K, V: Numeric](keyType: DataType, valueType: DataType) 
  extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    ...
```

use `Implicitly` to get it on runtime:

```
val n = implicitly[Numeric[V]]
```

and use its `plus` method in place of `+` an `zero` in place of `0`

```
buffer1(0) = map1 ++ map2.map{ 
  case (k,v) => k -> n.plus(v,  map1.getOrElse(k, n.zero))
}
```

To support wider set of types you can use [`cats`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) `Monoid`:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
```

and adjust the code:

```
class mySumToMap[K, V: Monoid](keyType: DataType, valueType: DataType) 
  extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    ...
```

and later:

```
override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
  val map1: Map[K, V] = buffer1.getMap[K, V](0)
  val map2: Map[K, V] = buffer2.getMap[K, V](0)

  val m = implicitly[Monoid[Map[K, V]]]

  buffer1(0) = m.combine(map1, map2)
}
```