# Generic iterator over dataframe (Spark/scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I need to iterate over data frame in specific order and apply some complex logic to calculate new column.

In below example I'll be using simple expression where current value for `s` is multiplication of all previous values thus it may seem like this can be done using UDF or even analytic functions. However, in reality logic is much more complex.

Below code does what is needed

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

val q = """
select 10 x, 1 y
union all select 10, 2
union all select 10, 3
union all select 20, 6
union all select 20, 4
union all select 20, 5
"""
val df = spark.sql(q)
def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]) : Iterator[Row] = {
  iter.scanLeft(Row(0,0,1)) {
    case (r1, r2) => {
      val (x1, y1, s1) = r1 match {case Row(x: Int, y: Int, s: Int) => (x, y, s)}
      val (x2, y2)     = r2 match {case Row(x: Int, y: Int) => (x, y)}
      Row(x2, y2, s1 * y2)
    }
  }.drop(1)
}
val schema = new StructType().
             add(StructField("x", IntegerType, true)).
             add(StructField("y", IntegerType, true)).
             add(StructField("s", IntegerType, true))
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
```

**Output**

```
scala> df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  s|
+---+---+---+
| 20|  4|  4|
| 20|  5| 20|
| 20|  6|120|
| 10|  1|  1|
| 10|  2|  2|
| 10|  3|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

What I do not like about it is

1) I explicitly define schema even though Spark can infer names and types for data frame

```
scala> df
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: int, y: int]
```

2) If I add any new column to data frame then I have to declare schema again and what is more annoying - re-define function!

Assume there is new column `z` in data frame. In this case I have to change almost every line in `f_row`.

```
def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]) : Iterator[Row] = {
  iter.scanLeft(Row(0,0,"",1)) {
    case (r1, r2) => {
      val (x1, y1, z1, s1) = r1 match {case Row(x: Int, y: Int, z: String, s: Int) => (x, y, z, s)}
      val (x2, y2, z2)     = r2 match {case Row(x: Int, y: Int, z: String) => (x, y, z)}
      Row(x2, y2, z2, s1 * y2)
    }
  }.drop(1)
}
val schema = new StructType().
             add(StructField("x", IntegerType, true)).
             add(StructField("y", IntegerType, true)).
             add(StructField("z", StringType, true)).
             add(StructField("s", IntegerType, true))
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
df.withColumn("z", lit("dummy")).repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
```

**Output**

```
scala> df.withColumn("z", lit("dummy")).repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
+---+---+-----+---+
|  x|  y|    z|  s|
+---+---+-----+---+
| 20|  4|dummy|  4|
| 20|  5|dummy| 20|
| 20|  6|dummy|120|
| 10|  1|dummy|  1|
| 10|  2|dummy|  2|
| 10|  3|dummy|  6|
+---+---+-----+---+
```

<s>**Is there a way to implement logic in more generic way so I do not need to create function to iterate over every specific data frame?**
Or at least to avoid code changes after adding new columns into data frame which are not used in calculation logic.</s>

Please see updated question below.

**Update**

Below are two options to iterate in more generic way but still with some drawbacks.

```
// option 1
def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
  val r = Row.fromSeq(Row(0, 0).toSeq :+ 1)
  iter.scanLeft(r)((r1, r2) => 
    Row.fromSeq(r2.toSeq :+ r1.getInt(r1.size - 1) * r2.getInt(r2.fieldIndex("y")))
  ).drop(1)
}
df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show

// option 2
def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
  iter.map{
    var s = 1
    r => {
      s = s * r.getInt(r.fieldIndex("y"))
      Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ s)
    }
  }
}
df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
```

If a new column added to data frame then initial value for iter.scanLeft has to be changed in Option 1. Also I do not really like Option 2 because it uses mutable var.

**Is there a way to improve the code so it's purely functional and no changes are needed when new column added to the data frame?**

Comment: [Use built-in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991640/cumulative-product-in-spark/52992103#52992103) (with `Window`) or use [generic UDAF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43248719) (with `Window`)  or [express the new schema in terms of the old schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105112)

Comment: @user6910411, thanks for your links, especially for the "schema" function, somehow I missed it earlier. Unfortunately, logic is complicated enough so that is not possible to implement it using window functions (whether built-in or user defined). I updated original post, please have a look if you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sufficient solution is below

```
def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
  if (iter.hasNext) {
    val head = iter.next
    val r = Row.fromSeq(head.toSeq :+ head.getInt(head.fieldIndex("y")))
    iter.scanLeft(r)((r1, r2) => 
      Row.fromSeq(r2.toSeq :+ r1.getInt(r1.size - 1) * r2.getInt(r2.fieldIndex("y"))))
  } else iter
}
val encoder = 
  RowEncoder(StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("s", IntegerType, false)))
df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
```

**Update**

Functions like getInt can be avoided in favor of more generic `getAs`.

Also, in order to be able to access rows of `r1` by name we can generate `GenericRowWithSchema` which is subclass of `Row`.

Implicit parameter has been added to `f_row` so that function can use current schema of the data frame and in the same time it can be used as a parameter of the `mapPartitions`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

implicit val schema = StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("result", IntegerType))
implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)

def mul(x1: Int, x2: Int) = x1 * x2;

def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row])(implicit currentSchema : StructType) : Iterator[Row] = {
  if (iter.hasNext) {
    val head = iter.next
    val r =
      new GenericRowWithSchema((head.toSeq :+ (head.getAs("y"))).toArray, currentSchema)

    iter.scanLeft(r)((r1, r2) =>
      new GenericRowWithSchema((r2.toSeq :+ mul(r1.getAs("result"), r2.getAs("y"))).toArray, currentSchema))
  } else iter
}

df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row).show
```

Finally, logic can be implemented in a tail recursive manner.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]) = {
  @tailrec
  def f_row_(iter: Iterator[Row], tmp: Int, result: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      val r = iter.next
      f_row_(iter, mul(tmp, r.getAs("y")),
        result ++ Iterator(Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ mul(tmp, r.getAs("y")))))
    } else result
  }
  f_row_(iter, 1, Iterator[Row]())
}

df.repartition($"x").sortWithinPartitions($"y").mapPartitions(f_row).show
```

Comment: This solution saved my life!! .Thanks a ton