# Avoid specifying schema twice (Spark/scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I need to iterate over data frame in specific order and apply some complex logic to calculate new column.

Also my strong preference is to do it in generic way so I do not have to list all columns of a row and do `df.as[my_record]` or `case Row(...) =>` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row/39433571#39433571). Instead, I want to access row columns by their names and just add result column(s) to source row.

Below approach works just fine but I'd like to avoid specifying schema twice: first time so that I can access columns by name while iterating and second time to process output.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

val q = """
select 2 part, 1 id
union all select 2 part, 4 id
union all select 2 part, 3 id
union all select 2 part, 2 id
"""
val df = spark.sql(q)

def f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]) : Iterator[Row] = {
  if (iter.hasNext) {
    def complex_logic(p: Int): Integer = if (p == 3) null else p * 10;

    val head = iter.next
    val schema = StructType(head.schema.fields :+ StructField("result", IntegerType))
    val r =
      new GenericRowWithSchema((head.toSeq :+ complex_logic(head.getAs("id"))).toArray, schema)

    iter.scanLeft(r)((r1, r2) =>
      new GenericRowWithSchema((r2.toSeq :+ complex_logic(r2.getAs("id"))).toArray, schema)
    )
  } else iter
}

val schema = StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("result", IntegerType))
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
df.repartition($"part").sortWithinPartitions($"id").mapPartitions(f_row)(encoder).show
```

**What information is lost after applying `mapPartitions` so output cannot be processed without explicit encoder? How to avoid specifying it?**

Comment: Can you use Dataset and provide a function that maps from T => U?

Comment: @TerryDactyl, can you elaborate a bit more? I use `df.repartition($"part").sortWithinPartitions($"id")` which is `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` and I supply `f_row(iter: Iterator[Row]) : Iterator[Row]` for `mapPartitions`.

Comment: A DataFrame is a Dataset[Row] and as discussed below Row is untyped. If you were to provide case classes T and U which correspond to the input and outputs shapes of your map function Iterator[T] => Iterator[U] and import spark.implicits._ then Spark may be able to provide an Encoder and you would effectively map from Dataset[T] => Dataset[U]. This is just a guess but may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below explanation sufficient, maybe it will be useful for others.

`mapPartitions` requires `Encoder` because otherwise it cannot construct `Dataset` from iterator or `Row`s. Even though each row has a schema, that shema cannot be derived (used) by constructor of `Dataset[U]`.

```
  def mapPartitions[U : Encoder](func: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U]): Dataset[U] = {
    new Dataset[U](
      sparkSession,
      MapPartitions[T, U](func, logicalPlan),
      implicitly[Encoder[U]])
  }
```

On the other hand, without calling `mapPartitions` Spark can use the schema derived from initial query because structure (metadata) of the original columns is not changed.

I described alternatives in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53177628/7869491.

Answer (score 0):

> What information is lost after applying mapPartitions so output cannot be processed without

The information is hardly lost - it wasn't there from the begining - subclasses of `Row` or `InternalRow` are basically untyped, variable shape containers, which don't provide any useful type information, that could be used to derive an `Encoder`.

`schema` in `GenericRowWithSchema` is inconsequential as it describes content in terms of metadata not types.

> How to avoid specifying it?

Sorry, you're out of luck. If you want to use dynamically typed constructs (a bag of `Any`) in a statically typed language you have to pay the price, which here is providing an `Encoder`.

Comment: I do not agree that "it wasn't there from the begining". I can show result after re-partitioning and ordering `df.repartition($"part").sortWithinPartitions($"id").show` but it's not possible after `mapPartitions`.

Comment: And function used in `mapPartitions` is `(func: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U])`. So why `show` can not be used if function produces pretty much the same records (with new columns to be precise) after iterating.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I have checked some of my spark code and using .mapPartitions with the Dataset API does not require me to explicitly build/pass an encoder.

You need something like:

```
case class Before(part: Int, id: Int)
case class After(part: Int, id: Int, newCol: String)

import spark.implicits._

// Note column names/types must match case class constructor parameters.
val beforeDS = <however you obtain your input DF>.as[Before]

def f_row(it: Iterator[Before]): Iterator[After] = ???

beforeDS.reparition($"part").sortWithinPartitions($"id").mapPartitions(f_row).show
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, "my strong preference is to do it in generic way so I do not have to list all columns of a row and do `df.as[my_record]` or `case Row(...) =>`". I want to avoid any changes if new columns added to data frame. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159461/generic-iterator-over-dataframe-spark-scala